# How to extract msg from channel.consume

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I was successfully consumed the message from rabbitmq, I can see the message if I add console.log(msg), but the problem is I can't get the msg outside the channel.consume

I tried to assign it to variable but it's still didn't work

```
const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost")
const channel = await connection.createChannel()
const queue = 'data-portal-response'

var messageString;
channel.consume(queue, msg => {
    console.log('Checking message...');
    if (msg !== null) {
        messageString = msg.content.toString();
        console.log('Acknowledging message..');
        channel.ack(msg);
        console.log('Acknowledged.');
        return messageString;
    } else {
        console.log('No messages to consume.');
        return null;
    }
});


console.log(messageString);
```

I'm expecting the code to print messageString outside the consume part
console.log(messageString);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following:

```
channel.consume(queue, msg => { ... });
```

Your expectation, stated below,

> I'm expecting the code to print messageString outside the consume part console.log(messageString);

is an unfortunate expectation. The code you have above executes a callback in an [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function with each received message. The arrow will inherit the scope from the parent context, but you cannot go the other direction. Thus, two things happen:

1. Consume is called, and
2. The string 'undefined' is logged to your console. That is because the next line to run is NOT inside the lambda, but is rather the `console.log(messageString)`, which at that time is undefined.

Instead, you need to move your `console.log` statement INSIDE the arrow function. If you need some other function to run in the parent scope (which I assume is what you need), then you'll have to define that as a separate function and call it from your arrow function.

For example:

```
let consumerTag = channel.consume(queue, msg => {
    console.log('Message received: ...');
    var messageString = msg.content.toString();
    this.doSomethingUsefulWith(messageString);

    console.log('Acknowledging message..');
    channel.ack(msg);
});

function doSomethingUsefulWith(messageString) { ... }
```